# System property value in spring config file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I configure queue name in camel route in Spring XML

```
    <camel:from uri="jms:queue:test.myqueue"/>
```

How to read queue name **test.myqueue** from system properties in this XML(Assume i start my application with -DqueueName=test.myqueue)

Also, if system property is not provided, is there a way configure default here?

Thanks
R

Comment: `<camel:from uri="jms:queue:${queueName:defaultValue}"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax to do it `${queueName:defaultValue}`. If a property or environment variable isn't provided then the default value will be taken.